# Aspectj throws "org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: malformed org.aspectj.weaver.PointcutDeclaration attribute" exception after Class Relocation

Tags: aspectj, maven-shade-plugin, aspectj-maven-plugin, jarjar

I'm using AspectJ on a project I'm working on.
As part of the project I was trying to use the "maven-shade-plugin" and the "jarjar-maven-plugin" in order to relocate classes from one jar to another.

In both cases, when I was trying to use the generated JAR, AspectJ failed with the following exception:

```
    Jan 12, 2016 7:18:52 PM org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error
SEVERE: register definition failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem processing attributes in io.myproject.MyAspect
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.<init>(BcelObjectType.java:162)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.buildBcelDelegate(BcelWorld.java:410)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:405)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:478)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:319)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryAspect(BcelWeaver.java:159)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerAspects(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:485)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerDefinitions(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:304)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:171)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(Aj.java:340)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.getWeavingAdaptor(Aj.java:345)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer.getWeaver(Aj.java:319)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: malformed org.aspectj.weaver.PointcutDeclaration attribute (length:530)org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: Bad type signature log


    at org.aspectj.weaver.AjAttribute.read(AjAttribute.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.readAjAttributes(Utility.java:101)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:383)
    ... 30 more

[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] warning register definition failed -- (RuntimeException) Problem processing attributes in io.myproject.MyAspect
Problem processing attributes in io.myproject.MyAspect
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem processing attributes in io.myproject.MyAspect
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.<init>(BcelObjectType.java:162)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.buildBcelDelegate(BcelWorld.java:410)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:405)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:478)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:319)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryAspect(BcelWeaver.java:159)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerAspects(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:485)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerDefinitions(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:304)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:171)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(Aj.java:340)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.getWeavingAdaptor(Aj.java:345)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer.getWeaver(Aj.java:319)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: malformed org.aspectj.weaver.PointcutDeclaration attribute (length:530)org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: Bad type signature log


    at org.aspectj.weaver.AjAttribute.read(AjAttribute.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.readAjAttributes(Utility.java:101)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:383)
    ... 30 more
```

I'll appreciate if you could point me out to what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: If you want to get a faster answer maybe it's a good idea to put up a self-contained minimal example that reproduces the problem. Then other people can jump in helping you. Currently only those people will be able to help you who saw the exact same behavior that you just described, which I think is very rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't use the maven-jarjar-plugin nor maven-shade plugin. I've used JarJar's JAR itself and that's solved the problem (since it doesn't modifiy the JAR with AspectJ during compile).

The answer of the following question describes the solution:

[Relocating fastxml.jackson classes to my.package.fastxml.jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764732/relocating-fastxml-jackson-classes-to-my-package-fastxml-jackson/34768338#34768338)